# Sort multiple levels of array after group in Mongo Java

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents with below schema

```
id : 
currencyCode : "USD"
businessDayStartDate : ""
hourZoneNumber : 1
customerCount : 0
itemQuantity : 4
nodeId : "STORE_DEV"
endpointId : "998"
amount : 4
```

I am trying to find documents that match nodeId and trying to aggregate customerCount, itemQuantity and amount for each hourZoneNumber.

Below is the query

```
db.getCollection("xxx").aggregate([
{ "$match": { "nodeId": { "$in":["STORE_DEV_1","STORE_DEV_2"] }, "businessDayStartDate" : { "$gte": "2022-03-04" , "$lte": "2022-03-07" } }},
{ "$group": {
       "_id": {
          "nodeId": "$nodeId",
          "endpointId": "$endpointId",
          "hourZoneNumber": "$hourZoneNumber"
       },
       "customerCount": { "$sum": "$customerCount" },
       "itemQuantity" : { "$sum": "$itemQuantity" },
       "amount" : { "$sum": "$amount" }
       
  }
},
{ "$group": {
       "_id": {
          "nodeId": "$_id.nodeId",
          "endpointId": "$_id.endpointId"
       },
       "hourZones": {
          "$addToSet": {
            "hourZoneNumber": "$_id.hourZoneNumber",
            "customerCount": { "$sum": "$customerCount" },
            "itemQuantity" : { "$sum": "$itemQuantity" },
            "amount" : { "$sum": "$amount" }
          }
       }
       
  }
},
{ "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id.nodeId",
       "endpoints": {
          "$addToSet": {
            "endpointId": "$_id.endpointId",
             "hourZones": "$hourZones"
          }
       },
       "total": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "customerCount": { "$sum": "$hourZones.customerCount" },
                "itemQuantity" : { "$sum": "$hourZones.itemQuantity" },
                "amount" : { "$sum": "$hourZones.amount" }
          }
       }
  }
},
{
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      nodeId: "$_id",
      endpoints: 1,
      hourZones: 1,
      total: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Output is as below:

```
{
  nodeId: 'STORE_DEV_2',
  endpoints: [ 
    { endpointId: '998',
       hourZones: 
        [ 
          { hourZoneNumber: 1,
            customerCount: 0,
            itemQuantity: 4,
            amount: Decimal128("4") }
        ] } ],
  total: [ { customerCount: 0, itemQuantity: 4, amount: Decimal128("4") } ],
}
{ 
  nodeId: 'STORE_DEV_1',
  endpoints: 
   [ { endpointId: '999',
       hourZones: 
        [ { hourZoneNumber: 2,
            customerCount: 2,
            itemQuantity: 4,
            amount: Decimal128("4") },
          { hourZoneNumber: 1,
            customerCount: 4,
            itemQuantity: 8,
            amount: Decimal128("247.56") } ] } ],
  total: 
   [ { customerCount: 6,
       itemQuantity: 12,
       amount: Decimal128("251.56") } ]
}
```

I want the output to be sorted as : First sort by nodeId, then by endpointId within the endpoints and lastly by hourZoneNumber within hourZones.

How do I do this ? I tried using sort() with all the three fields. But it did not work. Also, can someone please confirm if there is any better way than the above code, as I am new to Mongo DB.

Edit:
Please find sample input data at https://mongoplayground.net/p/FYm3QMMgrNI

Comment: Please add mock data to the question, preferably with a link to a working example on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) , so we'll be able to demonstrate a solution

Comment: I'm looking at your mock data, the current results are two documents. Do you want to sort these two by `nodeId`, then by the value of the first `endpointId ` from the endpoints array and then by the value of the first `hourZoneNumber` inside the  hourZones array of the first item on the endpoints array?

Comment: Yes. they have to be sorted in the order : nodeId, endpointId and hourZoneNumber. Each hourZones array has to be sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the separated data at the beginning, it is simply a matter of saving these values through the grouping and then sorting by them in the end.

Edit: In order to sort each inner array, we use `$push` instead of `$addToSet` inside the `$group` and `$sort` before each `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "nodeId": {"$in": ["STORE_DEV_TTEC", "STORE_DEV_TTEZ"]
      },
      "businessDayStartDate": {"$gte": "2022-03-04", "$lte": "2022-03-07"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {"nodeId": 1, "endpointId": 1, "hourZoneNumber": 1}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "nodeId": "$nodeId",
        "endpointId": "$endpointId",
        "hourZoneNumber": "$hourZoneNumber"
      },
      "customerCount": {"$sum": "$customerCount"},
      "itemQuantity": {"$sum": "$itemQuantity"},
      "amount": {"$sum": "$amount"}
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"_id.hourZoneNumber": 1}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "nodeId": "$_id.nodeId",
        "endpointId": "$_id.endpointId"
      },
      "hourZones": {
        "$push": {
          "hourZoneNumber": "$_id.hourZoneNumber",
          "customerCount": {"$sum": "$customerCount"},
          "itemQuantity": {"$sum": "$itemQuantity"},
          "amount": {"$sum": "$amount"}
        }
      },
      hourZoneKey: {$first: "$_id.hourZoneNumber"}
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"_id.endpointId": 1}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.nodeId",
      "endpoints": {
        "$push": {
          "endpointId": "$_id.endpointId",
          "hourZones": "$hourZones"
        }
      },
      endpointKey: {$first: "$_id.endpointId"},
      hourZoneKey: {$first: "$hourZoneKey"}
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"nodeId": 1, "endpointKey": 1, "hourZoneKey": 1}
  },
  {
    $project: {_id: 0, nodeId: "$_id", endpoints: 1, hourZones: 1, total: 1}
  }
])
```

You can see it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9PA_zM9aKbQ)

Comment: Thank you so much ! Just another question. I realized that the order of the keys will not be maintained inside the hourZones array as it is a set. So If I want them to be in a particular order, say hourZone has to be the first key, should I go for $push ?

Comment: The hourZones array is an array of objects. The order of object keys can't (and should not) be defined. If you will use `$push` you will create an array that is completely different...The query is about getting the data in the right format, not about presenting it...If you realy want you can create an array of key value pairs, that will look like this:  "hourZones": [
          [
            {k: "amount", v: NumberDecimal("41.86")},
            {k: "customerCount", v: 0},
            {k: "hourZoneNumber", v: 1},
            {k: "itemQuantity", v: 0}
          ]]

Comment: Will $first only sort the first value ? As when there are multiple objects under hourZones, it seems it is not sorted by hourZoneNumber

Comment: It should do the job. Please add a link to the playground with your example

Comment: Seems to work here https://mongoplayground.net/p/5XDBDY06j9_  Is it by any chance specific to a version of Mongo ? As in our project we are using 3.x

Comment: I don't think so, all the stages here are basic. What is the value of this x?

Comment: Mongo database is latest ( MongoDB 5.0.6 Community) and mongo-db-driver (dependency) used is 3.8.2. I will recheck my code also once.

Comment: When I run the same query multiple times, the sorting is different each time, even here  mongoplayground.net/p/5XDBDY06j9_ . The API result also varies, so does the query in Mongo compass. So kind of confused.

Comment: There is the "external" sorting of documents, which you ask for, and as far as I understand is working, and there is the "internal" sorting of each array inside the documents (endpoints array and hourZones array). If you are looking for sorting the internal arrays, you need to add a `$sort` step before each `$group` step, like I did here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/39_71xM6nqy , but in this case you can't use `$addToSet`

Comment: `$addToSet` is creating a set, not an array. Only arrays can be sorted. Sets can't be sorted, but they promise unique values (no duplication of values).

Comment: Thanks so much ! This was my original question, to be able to sort at all array levels. I will now try to convert this to Java.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly